# primeng angular2 rc5 can't load modules

Tags: angular, primeng

im using primeng in my angular2 project

and import it into the app.module.ts like this

```
    import {MenuModule,MenuItem} from 'primeng/primeng';
    @NgModule({
      imports: [MenuModule,MenuItem],
      bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
      schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]})
```

but i always got an error say that cannot find menuitem

i've already try to move menuitem to declaration and providers, also not find

but when i'm going to import another module its fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MenuItem is an interface in Primeng. You should be imported it when you have a type of MenuItem as below:

```
private items: MenuItem[];
```

So you don't need to declare it in the app.module.ts.
Also you can have a look at [here](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/components/common/api.ts) for more details.